# PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result()

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am new to programing not only with PHP but at all. Currently I am doing a siple project of mine to improve myself. I did it onec but now I want to make all my queries to work with prepared statements which is something new for me...

```
$create_stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO `users`(`user_name`, `password`) VALUES (?,?)");
    if(!$create_stmt){
        echo 'error';
        exit;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($create_stmt, 'ss',$username,$password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($create_stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($create_stmt, $new_uname, $new_unamepass);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($create_stmt);
```

So here is the deal. I am having this kind of an error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement.

Since I want to add 2 values to my 'users' table I am declaring 2 new variables `$new_uname`, `$new_unamepass`, but somehow this is not correct...

Also `mysqli_stmt_fetch($create_stmt);` is not TRUE but it should be if everything is OK (obviously its not ok..) So please if anyone can help me or give me some advice, it will be great!

Comment: Your INSERT query doesn't return any data like a SELECT query would.  So you probably want to delete your calls to bind_result and fetch.

Comment: I would highly suggest you try running this with objects. It greatly simplifies the code.

Comment: @Machavity: utterly useless "solution" going to OOP will not "simplify" ANY of this code.

Comment: insert queries don't RETURN any fields/rows. There is **NOTHING** for you to bind a result to.

Comment: BIG THANKS to you guys James, Marc and everyone. I didn't knew that INSERT doesn't return any data. I fixed my code and everything is working for now. Also I need to tell that I am not familiar with objects yet and that is the reason why I am not working with them for now but step by step I will start using them just like I did with the prepared statements :) Thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

TRY This:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`user_name`, `password`) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $pass);

$user='username';
$pass = 'Password1234';

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();
```